# EF6 Error: "The connection given is not of type 'SqlCeConnection'"

Tags: sql-server-ce, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a project which was running perfectly in EntityFramework 5. After upgrading the package to EF6, I haven't been able to resolve this error. I tried to uninstall and re-install the package, but still no go.

Here is my `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SqlServerCompact" version="4.0.8854.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact" version="4.0.8876.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <!--
  more entries removed for brevity
  -->
</packages>
```

Here is my `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- more entries removed for brevity -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Demo" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Demo.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <!-- more sections removed for brevity -->
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <contexts>
      <context type="Demo.Data.Context, Demo.Core">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[Demo.Data.Context, Demo.Core], [Demo.Web.Mvc.Seeder, Demo.Web.Mvc]], EntityFramework" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <!-- more entries removed for brevity -->
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Here is my `DbContext` Constructor:

```
namespace Demo.Data
{
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor sets the default connection string
        /// </summary>
        public Context()
            : base("Name=Demo") { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new context instance using the given string as the name or connection string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nameOrConnectionString"></param>
        public Context(string nameOrConnectionString)
            : base(nameOrConnectionString) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new context instance using the existing connection to connect
        ///     to a database
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="existingConnection">An existing connection to use for the new context.</param>
        /// <param name="contextOwnsConnection">If set to true the connection is disposed when the context is disposed, otherwise
        ///     the caller must dispose the connection.</param>
        public Context(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
            : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection) { }

     /** more code removed for brevity **/
    }
}
```

And here is the stack trace I get when trying to initialize the `DbContext`:

```
[ArgumentException: The connection given is not of type 'SqlCeConnection'.]
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +204
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +87

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +271
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +33

[ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.]
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +193
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ResolveManifestToken>b__0(Tuple`3 k) +32
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +180
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +56
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +43
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +62
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +123
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +611
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38
   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +63
   Demo.Web.Mvc.Controllers.LoginController.Index() in c:\Projects\Visual Studio\2012\Demo\Demo.Web.Mvc\Controllers\LoginController.cs:18
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514812
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I tried changing the connection string, but that did not help.

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you remove the binding redirect <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />? EF6 is not binary compatible with earlier EF versions so I don't think this binding redirect is valid. I have a feeling that the source of your problem here is that your app is trying to use EF6 in places where EF5 is expected (or vice versa) which causes problems. Also do you happen to have a reference to System.Data.Entity.dll in your project? if yes, remove it and see if it works - when using EF6 it is best to not have a reference to System.Data.Entity.dll.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same problem. I also upgraded my project from EF5 to EF6, but had forgotten about the Glimpse.EF5 extension. Once I removed the Glimpse.EF5 package the project ran fine.

Installing the matching Glimpse.EF6 extension restored the SQL tab.

Is it possible you are using Glimpse or similar functionality that may be wrapping your SQL connection with an incompatible object?